# How to plot the sigmoid function from a logistic regression model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I'm trying to solve this problem https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/wenruliu/adult-income-dataset

I've trained the data using the following code with a logistic regression model and got an accuracy of 0.8051589.

How do I plot the sigmoid function so I can better understand the model?

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('adultdata_encoded.csv')

# Assuming you have X as the feature matrix and y as the target variable
X = df[['education-num', 'workclass_encoded', 'hours-per-week', 'sex_encoded', 'relationship_encoded', 'occupation_encoded', 'maritalstatus_encoded', 'race_encoded', 'nativecountry_encoded']].values
y = df['income_encoded'].values

# Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Create a LogisticRegression object
logreg = LogisticRegression()

# Train the model on the training data
logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predict the target variable for the test data
y_pred = logreg.predict(X_test)

# Calculate the accuracy of the model
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
for i in range(0, len(y_pred)):
    print(y_pred[i], y_test[i])
print("Accuracy:", accuracy)
```

I've tried this code but can't figure out what `start`, `end`, and `num_points` should be

```
coef = logreg.coef_[0]
intercept = logreg.intercept_

# Define the sigmoid function
def sigmoid(x):
    z = np.dot(coef, x) + intercept
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))


# Generate input values within the desired range
start = 0  # define the start point
end = 1  # define the end point
num_points = 10  # define the number of points
x = np.linspace(start, end, num_points)

# Calculate predicted probabilities using the sigmoid function
y = sigmoid(x)

# Plot the sigmoid function
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('Input')
plt.ylabel('Probability')
plt.title('Sigmoid Function')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The start and end values depend on your data. For plotting the first coefficient, a reasonable value might be the minimum and maximum values of the first column. num_points is arbitrary. A high value approximates the sigmoid curve more accurately. A lower value is faster, because it evaluates fewer points.